# SharePoint 2013 Search Crawl Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Our SharePoint 2013 crawl log is showing this error for visio files :

> Processing this item failed because the parser server ran out of
>   memory. ( Error parsing document 'https://myteams.com/it/DC.vsdx'.
>   Document failed to be processed. It probably crashed the server.; ;
>   SearchID = 51A6E157-0918-4B5A-B5C3-FEEC0713FEAE )

Server has 16GB of RAM and do not see any issue with memory. File size is 23mb and this error is happening with couple of other visio files as well. I don't want to exclude this file from index if possible.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you changed this setting away from factory default.  Put it back to factory default.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Search\Runtime\1.0\noderunner.exe.config

## MEMORY ORIGINAL  "nodeRunnerSettings memoryLimitMegabytes="0""

Instead change this to this setting:

Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -PerformanceLevel Reduced

SharePoint 2013 is a Search memory hog and this service runs backwards from any other application I have ever supported.  By "reducing the CPU" it does not limit the CPU usage at all, instead it launches fewer loadrunner.exe.  Each loadrunning.exe needs unlimited RAM, if not I promise it will fail.

Comment: Thanks Duane. Based on your suggestion, I just ran the PowerShell command you provided. I will update again once issue seems resolved.

Comment: I forgot to say to restart the search service by restarting this "SPSearchHostController"

Comment: Duane, I noticed today that Incremental crawl is taking an hour to complete instead of couple of minutes prior to our changes. Also same error showed up again with the visio document. Also, I did started SPSearchHostController yesterday. Any idea?

Comment: That sounds like the full crawl worked?          Because your full crawl never worked before, it is natural for the incremental crawl to actually do something now that the full crawl works.

Comment: I have my full crawl set to start on Saturday at midnight.  Then I have my incremental set to run every hour and with this run frequency it takes 5 minutes.

Comment: If you don't mind, since the full crawl works and technically that is the scope of this question, could you please mark this as the correct answer?  If you have more questions, I will answer those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48961/discussion-between-kauser-and-duane-lawrence).